# How can I connect a Logitech MX 1100 mouse & Wave 2.4 keyboard with the Unifying Receiver?

Tags: logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I recently acquired a unifying receiver. My mouse is an MX 1100 with a Wave 2.4 keyboard. The receiver that came with this is as big as a USB. So, I got a smaller receiver.

Using the Logitech Unifying Software (on Windows 10), I tried pairing them. I tried both at the same time, the mouse only, the keyboard only, but nothing works for me. I went into advanced options and saved the System Report and found the following;

```
[19:02:47:0782]: ----------[05-10-2017]------------------------- Unifying API ------------------------------------

[19:02:47:0782]: <9220>Unifying Loaded DLL: 2.50.25

[19:02:48:0298]: <5560>HID++ contention false positive error detected (Idx:0xFF. Threshold:1.0 ms).

[19:02:48:0798]: <5560>HID++ contention false positive error detected (Idx:0xFF. Threshold:0.9 ms).

[19:02:48:0811]: <10864> Unable to read device (0x31015) name. Reason:0x8.

[19:02:48:0814]: <10864>Unable to read device (0x31015) pairing info. Reason:0x8.

[19:02:48:0816]: <10864> Unable to read device (0x32003) name. Reason:0x8.

[19:02:48:0818]: <10864>Unable to read device (0x32003) pairing info. Reason:0x8.

[19:02:58:0890]: <7756>Failed to read activity counter. Polling thread aborted.

Log content displays the 100% of the available one.
```

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a unifying logo on your device? I searched your models in logitech's support page and there is no mention of "unifying". I doubt they are compatible with their unifying receiver.